# java - Injecting proxies via CDI

Tags: java, cdi

in my project I have some external Java interfaces (so I can't change them).
E.g.

```
public interface Abc
{
    void do123();
}
```

in a bean I like to use this interface by injection.
E.g.

```
public class TestAbc
{
    @Inject
    private Abc abc;
}
```

But I don't have a implementation of this interface or a producer method. Instead I'm looking for a way to inject a generic proxy for this interface.

I guess, that I need something like a cdi extension for doing things like this. Unfortunatelly I can't find any good how to for this.
In a optimal world I would expect to implement a method like this.

```
public Object produce( Class< ? > type )
{
    if(isMyType(type))
    {
        // I can produce this type
        return createProxy(type);
    }
    return null; // this method can't produce this type
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Regards
Johannes

Comment: Have a look at this: https://bitbucket.org/marembo2008/khameleon/src/4231200bb5b618e3e4cae569f111115685f4e1dd/khameleon-spi/src/main/java/com/anosym/khameleon/core/spi/extension/ConfigServiceExtension.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? If the interfaces don't have an implementation, what do you expect to inject? What would the "proxy" do? You always need some actual implementation, so either you implement it, or some other library does.

Comment: @Siliarus My idea is that a java proxy can "fake" this interface. My concrete use case is the injection of a EJB RMI interface in my client. For the different RMI interfaces the product method looks always very similar. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI lookupRemoteStatefulCounter() . The needed parameters for a specific interface I like to store in a propery file and load it into the proxy.

Answer (score 3):

So, finally I got it.
For my use case I needed an CDI extension which listens to the ProcessInjectionPoint and the AfterBeanDiscovery.
ProcessInjectionPoint collects all relevant interfaces for injection and AfterBeanDiscovery creates beans for this interfaces.

The check if an inject is relevant or not is done by an annotation with @RMI. @RMI is an own qualifier annotation. RMILifecyle is responsible for build or destroy the injected object.
Here some source code.

```
public class RMIInjectionExtension implements Extension
{
    private Set< Class< ? > > interfaces = Sets.newHashSet();

    void processInjectionPoint( @Observes final ProcessInjectionPoint< ?, ? > aProcessInjectionPoint )
    {
        // collecting all relevant interfaces
        if( aProcessInjectionPoint.getInjectionPoint().getQualifiers().stream()
            .anyMatch( RMI.class::isInstance ) )
        {
            interfaces.add( (Class< ? >)aProcessInjectionPoint.getInjectionPoint().getType() );
        }
    }

    void afterBeanDiscovery( @Observes final AfterBeanDiscovery aAfterBeanDiscovery,
        BeanManager aBeanManager )
    {
        // create beans for the interfaces
        // using DeltaSpike BeanBuilder
        interfaces.stream().map( a -> new BeanBuilder< Object >( aBeanManager ).beanClass( a )
            .qualifiers( (RMI)() -> RMI.class ).beanLifecycle( new RMILifecyle() ).create() )
            .forEach( aAfterBeanDiscovery::addBean );
    }
}
```

This works quite well for me.